# Linux Ubuntu 18 - Keyboard layout is incorrect, but all settings are default

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, layout

My laptop keyboard is vanilla qwerty US English (not international). I've verified this using [this guide.](https://keyshorts.com/blogs/blog/44712961-how-to-identify-laptop-keyboard-localization)

I'm currently typing this on a USB keyboard, which works normally, but the keyboard built into my laptop types incorrect letters in certain places. Anywhere below the number keys, to the right of the y/h/n column of keys. For example:

```
m -> 0
j -> 1
k -> 2
l -> 3
u -> 4
i -> 5
o -> 6
p -> *
; -> -
0 -> / # the only key on the number line which is messed up
```

... and so forth. The left side of the keyboard seems to work just fine though - the 'a' key types 'a', 'q' types 'q', etc.

When I first installed the OS, I'm relatively certain that the keyboard on the laptop was working, but i haven't changed any localization or keyboard configurations aside from remapping my caps lock key to control in `/etc/default/keyboard`.

I also tried booting into a live USB of Ubuntu 18 and the laptop keyboard was working normally, and yet all the settings I know of are identical to the live USB. So there must be some configuration file somewhere that was changed.

Output of `setxkbmap -print -verbose`:

```
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+inet(evdev)+ctrl(nocaps)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+ctrl(nocaps)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

`setxkbmap -query`:

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
options:    ctrl:nocaps
```

Content of `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/when-i-type-my-laptop-keyboard-alphabet-j-it/7ece24b7-c1e2-4ec7-aaf4-edfd62b37104

Turns out my numlock was turned on through my USB keyboard and this affected the settings on my laptop directly.

To prevent this in the future, i did the reverse of [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock), ensuring numlock is always disabled by default on boot.

Or just disable it from the command line:

```
sudo apt instlal numlockx # if needed 
numlockx off
```

Comment: Wow who would've thought... This solved my problem too after several days of thinking about it.